# word2vec vocab vs char

Tags: python, word2vec

I'm using word2vec to represent my words as vectors.

```
text = np.loadtxt("file.txt", dtype=str, delimiter=" ")
word2vec = w2v.Word2Vec(text, size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
print(len(word2vec.wv.vocab))
```

text is a list of words(strings). Instead of printing the number of words, this code prints 26, # English letters. In order to train word2vec to my model, I need to be dealing with words, not letters. I've tried converting text to a string, but it wasn't successful. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `text` is a list of words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to pass a list of lists of words:

```
word2vec = w2v.Word2Vec(text.reshape(-1, 1), size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
```

Comment: I think it's working. Thank you. Do you know if it counts the number of unique words or are repeated words double counted?

Comment: @COLDSPEED So I can now build the vectors, but I don't think my model captures the relationship between words very well. For example, print model.similarity('big', "large") is -0.0257764676135. Do you have an idea to fix it? I know that I can use Google's pre-built model, but using that does not represent my text at all. Is there a way to use the pre-built model and train that to my model?

Comment: I guess I can do this

model =  KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
model.build_vocab(text, update=True)
model.train(text)

but I get 
AttributeError: 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'build_vocab'. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @HYUNJAECHO You need quite a bit of text to get meaningful vector relationships. How large is your corpus, in word count?

Comment: @HYUNJAECHO Hmm, this needs another pair of eyes. Ask a new question perhaps?

Comment: @COLDSPEED my corpus contains 30K words. I know it's not big enough, but I didn't know it would be this bad. It'd be better off to use the pre-built model, I guess?

Comment: @HYUNJAECHO maybe but only if the custom corpus doesn't have any particular semantics that the pretrained model doesn't give.